# Error with Super Tabs in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir05p.png)

I watched several YT videos or posts in forums about super-tabs and did it exactly like it was shown. But somehow it is not working:( Do you have a solution or is super-tabs just not working anymore? (I created a default tabs project to show this problem. So its a deafault ionic tabs project. Nothing is changed except the code I posted above. So when I change the super-tabs back to ion-tabs, Everything is normal. That’s the reason why I thought it has to be some kind of a bug. The W is from welcome to Ionic(default text). And the overlaying action is only taking place with the super-tabs.)

```
app.module.ts

import { SuperTabsModule } from "ionic2-super-tabs";
...
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    SuperTabsModule.forRoot(),

  ],

tabs.html

<super-tabs>
  <super-tab [root]="tab1Root" title="Home" icon="home"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="tab2Root" title="About" icon="information-circle"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="tab3Root" title="Contact" icon="contacts"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

Comment: what do you mean it's not working can you elaborate? Have you defined tab1Root page?